# How to highlight a certain time range in an Excel column of datetimes?

Tags: excel, datetime, time, office-2016

I have an excel column of datetime items in the European format of **`2020.10.26 13:14:00`**, and I would like to highlight those rows where the time fall between `11:00:00` and `12:00:00`.

Anything Google turned up for *conditional formatting* is mostly related to *dates*, but they don't work for the *time*.

**How can I highlight a certain time range in an Excel column of datetimes?**
(Is there a formula?)

---

Tried suggestion shown below, but without success.

[image]

---

**UPDATE**: 2020-10-30

If you are copy/pasting (or importing/using) a date *text* that is using the *dot* notation (`2020.10.26`), Excel will not be able to understand it, unless your computers (Windows) *locale* is set to use that same notation. Most common are the US *slash* (`26/10/2020`), or European *dash* (`2020-10-26`) notations. Excel will then refuse to recognize it as a date even if you specifically set it to a *Date* (or *Custom*) under the *`Format Cell...`* drop-down settings. Instead it will still be treated as *text*, and you will have to convert it to a *standard* date notation without dots).

By default, Excel likes to put "text" as left justified, while real *date* cells are right justified.

In my case I could convert my date text from using dots to dashes, by using the Excel formula:

```
'=SUBSTITUTE(TEXT(A2,"00.00"),".","-")
```

<sub>(Here the `00.00` acts as a template field.)</sub>

However, this means you need to create a new column with all those newly formatted dates. This is not a very sexy solution, the better ones are fund in the accepted solutions provided by @basic below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use formula for conditional formatting:

```
=(HOUR(A1)>=11)*(HOUR(A1)<12)
```

[image]

**Edit**

If you have date entered as text, use formula:

```
=((MID(C1,12,2))*1)=11
```

[image]

Comment: This look promising, but it doesn't work for me. Maybe because I also have seconds? Also, I am using the *date* format for that column.

Comment: @not2qubit The formula takes an hour part of the datetime and compares it to the required period - no matter whether the cell has seconds or not and how the cell is formatted. Edit your question and add a screenshot with the data, used formula and applies to range

Comment: I did exactly that and several variations, but no go. I also tried to format the column with a custom format variation for time (`yyyy.mm.dd hh:mm:ss`), to mach that shown in OP.  (All my data look like that, just different time and dates.) However, I see your formula is using flat `A1` which actually contain the column name `DateTime`, whereas mine is called `MyTime`. Maybe that is important? (Nope, just tried that too.) Why don't you try adding a *seconds* field (`:ss`) to your data, and see if that formula still works for you?

Comment: Also, what settings do you have for *format cells* for that column?

Comment: @not2qubit My datetime has seconds, just column is formatted without them. Your CF look OK, but your dates seems not. Can you show me result of formula ```=ISNUMBER(A2)```?

Comment: It's `FALSE` since it is not a number but a *Date* or *Custom* field formatted as the date I described above.

Comment: @not2qubit my answer was for question _How can I highlight a certain time range in an Excel column of datetimes?_ For text see edit.

Comment: Indeed! Because of lacking MSO documentation, it seem that if you get/paste a date formatted in *dot* notation, while your *locale* settings are using a *dash* notation for separating the date items (as I have), Excel is not able to recognize it as a proper date and instead think it is text, even if you format it manually to be a "date" or "custom" date. (This can bee seen as the date column is left justified, while a properly recognize date, is right justified (by default). If I replace the `.` with `-`, then it works. (I have no idea how to make custom formatting as the docs are lacking.)

Comment: To replace "dots" with "dashes", I used: `'=SUBSTITUTE(TEXT(A2,"00.00"),".","-")`

Comment: Excel has a problem with using the formula you added last. It has 2 equal signs in it: `=((MID(C1;12;2))*1)=11`. My guess is that it's missing something making it a boolean.

Comment: What's the problem? If you enter this formula in a cell, you will see the exact result.

Comment: No, the MID function should have commas, not semicolons, like this: `=((MID(C1,12,2))*1)=11`. Anyway, I appreciate you patience. Thank you.

Comment: Oh, yes. I use semicolons and forgot replace. Sorry. Fixed.